# Dynamically alter mongoose schema according to rows added in html table form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a Mongoose schema as such :

```
const metricsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
week : Number,
level : String,
details: {
    demo: String,
    full: String
    } 
});
```

I also created a POST API in node js to insert data into this schema. My current POST API :

```
router.post('/',(req, res, next)=>{
    const metrics = new Metrics({
        _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        level : req.body.level,
        week : req.body.week,
        details:{
            demo: req.body.demo,
            full: req.body.full
        } 
    });
    metrics
        .save()
        .then(() => {
            res.redirect('/form.html');
    })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({error : err});
        });
});
```

I am taking data from an HTML form table and storing it in Mongo DB using the POST API. 
One row of the table when added returns the output in the given above structure. I want to dynamically add rows to the table and hence modify the mongoose schema dynamically to change the schema structure when more than 1 row of data is added to the form.
For example, if two rows are added, then the mongoose schema should look like this :

```
const metricsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
week : Number,
level : String,
details: {
    demo: String,
    full: String
    },
level : String,
details: {
    demo: String,
    full: String
    } 
});
```

How will I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The above is not possible since you can't have object properties with the same name (you are duplicating `level` and `details` for each additional row of the table), and this is not a limitation of mongoose but Javascript itself.

I think you just want to have an array of these, so your schema would be:

```js
const metricsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
week : Number,
level : [String],
details: {
    demo: [String],
    full: [String]
    }
});
```

or

```js
const metricsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
week : Number,
//whatever property name instead of `rows`
rows: [
   level : String,
   details: {
       demo: String,
       full: String
       }
   ]
});
```

You should play a bit with it the way you want it structured, but arrays seem what you want.